# Can dao350.dll get corrupted in memory and corrupt new connections?

Tags: dll, vb6, dao, windows-server-2012

We are trying to resolve a problem involving Access Database connections. Everything goes fine for hours or days. Then a program gets a page fault error. After that, every program on the network is unable to communicate with their access databases until every program using access is shut down.

The programs are VB6 (yeah I know).

They use DAO350.dll by using the reference:

dao2535.tlb#Microsoft DAO 2.5 Object Library

It seems like we have orphan dlls in memory - they don't belong to a process.

See the image.

Has anyone encountered this? If so how did you resolve it?

Our programs are running on Server 2012 (that seems to be the only system this happens on if that helps).

I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

Thanks.
[image: orphans?]

Answer (score 1):

First, pls do not apologize for using old code.

I can still do things with vb6 and even vb5 that are almost impossible with any of the newer 'lock down' ugly semantic stuff we have today.

My guess is that you are declaring recordsets within the code that are not being correctly terminated.

To explain,

Both vb5 and vb6 always claimed that a private variable, or procedure variable went out of scope when the procedure finished.

But, this was not true for recordset variables.

Assume the following

```
Dim dbs as database
Dim rst as recordset
dim sSQL$

Set dbs = CurrentDb

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME"
Set rst = dbs.openrecordset(sSQL)

    ... Do Things

Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = nothing
```

So, we assume that rst went out of scope (closed, freed up memory).

It did not!

One *Must* Affirmatively Close the rst object

```
rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Otherwise the mem is occupied, albeit orphaned.

Over time, this creates a 'memory leak'.  When the memory gets re-used, it causes the problem you describe.  Kinda like clogged arteries causing a heart attack.

You should inspect the code to make sure that all rst objects (including rst clones) are being closed.

This assumes you are not using API's to move memory around.   This can also cause similar issues, but I doubt they would build up over time (like a heart attack).  Move memory issues are more like a shiv in the gut than a heart attack.  They happen straight away and are far easier to find.

hth,

Gary